# LinkButton Won't Trigger Command Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, event-handling

I know there are a lot of related posts or articles about this, but then it seems that they're not helping my case. I've even compared with a working sample at this site, http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-LinkButton-Command-Event.aspx, I don't think there's much difference. I thought my code should be working but apparently it just won't. I'm so sorry if this looks like a duplicate, but it's my last resort to post here.

Here's my HTML:

```
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="AppsList">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="applist">
                <div class="app">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnApp" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Icon") %>' height="100" width="100" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' OnCommand="AppsList_ItemCommand" />
                </div>
                <div class="appname">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbtnAppName" runat="server" CommandName="Select" ForeColor="#333333" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' OnCommand="AppsList_ItemCommand" CssClass="linkbtnAppName"><%# Eval("AppName") %></asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>

        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            Sorry - Nothing found.
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Code:

```
protected void AppsList_ItemCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        txtTest.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to capture the ID of the item in the ListView into the textbox when I click on either the Image Button or Link Button. Both will perform the same thing. I already got the Image button to work. When I click the Image, the ID, e.g 1 will appear in the textbox. But when I want to do the same thing with the Link Button, nothing will happen. The event is not being triggered in any way.

I've seen some posts talking about repeaters or AJAX to do the same thing, but I was just wondering why can't this code work. I would appreciate any pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in case someone is wondering why this is happening, this is what I've found out after spending a great deal of time ripping off my codes to see what's wrong with it. I doubt that someone will bump into this issue, but to heck with it, sharing is caring.

Apparently the search button I've placed in my master page is the reason behind this. I've assigned its ID as "submit", which is the thing that is stopping my linkbutton from working, which I have no idea why that is happening. The search function is merely a search engine allowing users to look for the keywords in the webpage. The linkbutton's OnCommmand event just won't trigger when the ID to the search button is assigned as "submit".

When I change it to "submit1", everything works as normal. I'm still a newbie in this asp.net thing, can anyone tell me why is this even affecting the linkbutton? Anyway, the OnCommand event is now working properly.

Comment: As far as the "why" of it, you should open a separate question for that.

Answer (score 1):

For my own experience, I have wrongly set  `ViewStateMode="Disabled"` in page directive.

Because of this when post back occur upon clicking LinkButton inside the List View, existing data are vanished. So, will not reach to LinkButton's OnCommand event and never fire.

Once ViewStateMode attribute is removed, everything working well.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your eventArgs should ListViewCommandEventArgs instead of CommandEventArgs and you should also bind the itemCommand event to your aspx page as shown below.

ASPX:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="AppsList" OnItemCommand="AppsList_OnItemCommand">
```

Code Behind:

```
 protected void AppsList_OnItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if (String.Equals(e.CommandName, "Select"))
    {
    }
  }
```

UPDATE:

Also remove the OnCommand attribute from image button and Link button OnCommand="AppsList_ItemCommand" , and each CommandName should be different than other.

```
    <div class="applist">
        <div class="app">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnApp" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Icon") %>' height="100" width="100" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  />
        </div>
        <div class="appname">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbtnAppName" runat="server" CommandName="Select" ForeColor="#333333" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' CssClass="linkbtnAppName"><%# Eval("AppName") %></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Nope, it's not working. If I put it this way, the image button won't work as well.

Comment: i figured out another problem . let me update my post shortly

Comment: same, it's still not working. Actually I tried the ListViewCommandEventArgs yesterday, not working so I changed to CommandEventArgs, which returned the result I wanted to see. But then the LinkButton just won't work with my original method and also your suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with LinkButtons. I don't remember how I figured this out, but I must of got fustrated and started clicking the LinkButton a few times fairly quickly and I noticed that the Command event did fire once in awhile. Soon I figured it's if I clicked on the LinkButton before the page fully loads that the command would fire correctly. If the page fully loaded then it seems something was hijacking that command on the LinkButton.

Without success, from one of the other suggestions I searched for any button that might be using the name/id "submit". There wasn't one on my page.

With success, I tried using ASP.Net Buttons instead of LinkButtons. That seemed to fix my issue. I'm not entirely sure what caused this situation but Buttons seem to work in my case so I'll stick with that.